# Cloudinary reverse photos order after create/update on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I'm using [cloudinary](https://github.com/longform/cloudinary_gem) and [attachinary](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary) gems to upload photos which will be exhibited on a carousel and the order is important to me.

Update:

What is happening is that when we call:

```
product = Product.find(id)
product.photo.count # it returns many photos from attachinary
> 12
first_photo = product.photo.first
```

In production:

- `first_photo` returns the last photo created (greater id number)

In development/staging:

- `first_photo` returns the first photo created (lesser id number)

Atachinary creates this table:

```
  create_table "attachinary_files", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "attachinariable_type"
    t.integer  "attachinariable_id"
    t.string   "scope"
    t.string   "public_id"
    t.string   "version"
    t.integer  "width"
    t.integer  "height"
    t.string   "format"
    t.string   "resource_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.index ["attachinariable_type", "attachinariable_id", "scope"], name: "by_scoped_parent", using: :btree
  end
```

Specs:

- Rails: 5.0.1
- Attachinary: 1.3.1
- Cloudinary: 1.1.1

Table

- products
- attachinary field: photo

**Product.rb**

```
has_attachments :photo, maximum: 20, accept: [:jpg, :jpeg, :jfif, :bmg, :bpg, :png]
```

Comment: Can you share some more code? The view that displays the resources, the controller, and the upload form.

Comment: Hi, I updated the explanation

Comment: Try to run `product.photo.first` in the terminal in both environments. You should be able to see the specific SQL query. Something like: `SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1`. Are they identical in both environments? Specifically, the `ORDER BY` part

Answer (score 0):

We can turn around by adding ordering by id all the time that we need to display the photos. On the product#edit view we can see that the small pictures in attachinary order remains "reversed" on production in my case but I think that it is not a major problem since we have the id to trace the correct order.